# How does spin transform under transformations in 1+1D?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, conformal-field-theory

I'm considering a Hamiltonian consisting of Pauli spin matrices, $\sigma^i$ in a 1+1D system with of one spatial and one temporal dimension, $(t, x)$. Suppose I then make a transformation

\begin{align*}
x^\mu \rightarrow x'^\mu = \Lambda^\mu {}_\nu x^\nu
\end{align*}

I want to determine how my Hamiltonian transform in this case, i.e. how the Pauli spin matrices transform. How do I express my space-time transformation matrix $\Lambda^\mu {}_\nu$ in spin space?

Comment: There are no rotations in 1D.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want to say with that, so please elaborate. To make myself clearer, I working in a 1+3 system truncated into the 1+1. The spin operators therefore still resembles those from the 1+3 case. I want to know how these are affected when making a transformation in the 1+1 system, which also lives in the 1+3 system. I'm quite positive that we have 1+1 transformations (inversion, boosts, etc.). Do you see, what I'm asking?